# Changing div position with scroll direction

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, direction

I was looking for a way to change a div position based on scroll direction using Javascript only.

I found a [great resource](https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant/pen/ryrrGx) from [lehollandaisvolant](https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant) on CodePen which got me on the right track. (Big thank you!) This code outputs html content that displays the direction which the user is scrolling.

Here is the original code:

**HTML**

```html
<p>Because i’m sick of using tons of shit for this basic function.</p>
<p>This uses no timing functions, no jQuery and fits everywhere.</p>
<pre>
  Scroll me.
  Scroll me.
  Scroll me.
  Scroll me.
  Scroll me.
  Scroll me.
</pre>
<div id="info-box" data-scroll-direction="no scrolling yet, go on!">
  Your last scolling direction was: 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#info-box {
  padding: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px silver;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  }
#info-box::after {
  content: attr(data-scroll-direction);
  }
pre {
  line-height: 250px;
  }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

````js
var scrollPos = 0;   // Initial state

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){  // adding scroll event

  // detects new state and compares it with the new one
  if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos)
    document.getElementById('info-box').setAttribute('data-scroll-direction', 'UP');
  else
    document.getElementById('info-box').setAttribute('data-scroll-direction', 'DOWN');
    
  // saves the new position for iteration.
  scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the div position however, I simply changed the If/Else statement to fit my desired css criteria:

```
// Initial state
var scrollPos = 0;
// adding scroll event
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  // detects new state and compares it with the new one
  if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos)
        document.getElementById('info-box').style.margin = '100px 0 0 0';
    else
        document.getElementById('info-box').style.margin = '0px 0 0 0';
    scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
});
```

Specifically:

```
if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos)
        document.getElementById('info-box').style.margin = '100px 0 0 0';
    else
        document.getElementById('info-box').style.margin = '0px 0 0 0';
```

Hopefully someone may find this useful in trying to change a div's css position based on scroll direction, or trying to do something similar.